# Store user-related information in .net apps

Tags: .net, registry, storage, config

What is the preferred way to store user-level information for .NET application?

I could use registry or config files - but some users don't have enough permissions to save/load from these.

I have heard something about assembly private storage or something like that, is it a way to go?

My main concern is to make sure that even users with a minimal set of privileges could be able to access this storage location.

Answer (score 5):

How about [User-scoped Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171565.aspx)? (They're stored locally in each user's Local Settings folder.) You can [create the settings file using the VS designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6.aspx) as well, and they're pretty easy to maintain.

There's more information from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx) about the Application Settings architecture in general, with quite a few more links on that page.

Comment: what about required user permission. let's say if I run my app under most restricted account (user-account) - is it (User-scoped Applicaiton Settings) going to work in my case? Thank you LC.

Comment: Unless something's really strange, all users have full access to their own Local Settings folder, so there will be no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my.settings . Check this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611(VS.80).aspx) from msdn.

Comment: That is (unfortunately) vb specific.

Answer (score 0):

Most applications nowadays use some sort of database to store information. SQL Express and SQLLite can server this purpose.